# How can I measure the time of importing data from csv file to Hbase?

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hbase

I import data from file `logs.csv` to Hbase table using command `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,log" logs hdfs://ip:9000/tmp/logs.csv`. At the end of the executing command I get a summary shown below however there is no information on how long it took to add data to the Hbase. Do you have any idea how can I check this?

```
    2018-10-06 23:09:17,647 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.Task: Final Counters for attempt_local1534176268_0001_m_000001_0: Counters: 21
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=37162012
        FILE: Number of bytes written=37835107
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=162892986
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=4
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=175896
        Map output records=175896
        Input split bytes=106
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=18
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=2075918336
    ImportTsv
        Bad Lines=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=28671162
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
2018-10-06 23:09:17,647 INFO  [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local1534176268_0001_m_000001_0
2018-10-06 23:09:17,647 INFO  [Thread-37] mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
2018-10-06 23:09:18,191 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1534176268_0001 completed successfully
2018-10-06 23:09:18,220 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Job: Counters: 21
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=74323793
        FILE: Number of bytes written=75670214
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=297114810
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=7
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=1000000
        Map output records=1000000
        Input split bytes=212
        Spilled Records=0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=55
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=4151836672
    ImportTsv
        Bad Lines=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=162892986
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

**LOGS**

```
2018-10-16 09:39:53,350 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Stopping IPC Server Responder
2018-10-16 09:39:53,350 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeResourceMonitorImpl is interrupted. Exiting.
2018-10-16 09:39:53,351 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Public cache exiting
2018-10-16 09:39:53,352 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NodeManager metrics system...
2018-10-16 09:39:53,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system stopped.
2018-10-16 09:39:53,353 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NodeManager metrics system shutdown complete.
2018-10-16 09:39:53,354 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Call From myserver/myip to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:684)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call From myserver/myip to 0.0.0.0:8031 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor30.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:732)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.impl.pb.client.ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.registerNodeManager(ResourceTrackerPBClientImpl.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.registerNodeManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:232)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:788)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3500(Client.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1381)
    ... 22 more
2018-10-16 09:39:53,358 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at myserver/myip
************************************************************/
```

Answer (score 0):

It is map/reduce job, you can see the execution time in yarn UI. it's default port is 8088.

Comment: No, in  http://yarn-master-ip:8088 you can see the list of jobs and in each job details is available.

Comment: I mean `http://localhost:8088/cluster`. `http://localhost:8088` works but I don't see any list of jobs in `http://localhost:8088/cluster`.

Comment: Run job again, if you haven't history server list clears every time you restart yarn.

Comment: No, Total memory and number of vcores is 0! your cluster isn't healthy

Comment: But logs look good. HDFS, Hbase etc. work properly. So what may be wrong?

Comment: Hdfs is ok but yarn is not ok, hdfs and yarn is independent, look your yarn and map reduce configuration. Hbase is on Hdfs.

Comment: I added my `yarn-site.xml` to the question however in case of `mapred-site.xml` it looks as there is no such file. `sudo find / -name mapred-site.xml` returns only `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/mapred-site.xml
/etc/hadoop/conf.pb_cluster/mapred-site.xml
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/example-confs/conf.pseudo/mapred-site.xml
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/example-confs/conf.secure/mapred-site.xml`

Comment: Is resourcemanager on master and nodemanager on slaves running?

Comment: Only ResourceManager is running on master. NodeManagers are not running on slaves.

Comment: Run them too, they must run

Comment: At the moment my `master:8088` looks in this way https://ibb.co/e8r3WL. Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it looks ok!

Comment: Okay, so where can I check now the execution time of `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,log" logs hdfs://ip:9000/tmp/logs.csv`?

Comment: Rahim, do you have some free time to talk about hadoop?

Comment: Yes, let's chat

Comment: Skype or chat here?

Comment: I think here is better

Comment: Okay. I do not know if you remember, but I mentioned you that I'm working on a web application. Something like dropbox with data analysis. I need to send files of any size and format in the fastest possible way to Hadoop. I would like to support both private users and companies. I wonder if you have any ideas how I could do this? At the moment I try to upload files using webhdfs. It works properly with small files but there are a lot of problems when sending large files and I am not sure if this is a good way?

Comment: ummm skype is better!! ;)

Comment: Hello Rahim, do you have some free time to talk about the process of preparing and loading HFiles to Hbase?

Comment: Hello I send a message in skype